# How can I tell which version of CIFs is in the kernel if CIFs module isn't loaded?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, linux-kernel, cifs

I need to determine the CIFs version that exists in my kernel, but the CIFs module isn't loaded.

```
my-user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ modinfo kernel/fs/cifs.ko
modinfo: ERROR: Module kernel/fs/cifs.ko not found.
```

When I run `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*'` in the list of results I see `/lib/modules/4.15.0-1058-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko`

How can I find out what version of cifs.ko exists, awaiting potential use, in my kernel?  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `modinfo` (if you are not root you might need the full path) with the name of the module:

```
$ /sbin/modinfo cifs
```

Comment: That did it--I was just using the wrong path and I didn't realize it would work without the full path.  Thanks!